# CEFSharp within AddIn - "Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains"

Tags: .net, add-in, appdomain, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm programming an AddIn for Solid Edge using the *SolidEdge Community AddIn*. With this AddIn, an EdgeBar containing a website should be displayed.

Because I don't want to use the standard Windows Forms WebBrowser control (it only uses the IE rendering engine), I try to use the *Chromium Embedded Framework* with its .NET bindings *CEFSharp* (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp).

When creating a fresh Windows Forms Application, embedding the CEFSharp control works just fine. But when I embed it in my AddIn code, I receive this following error after starting Solid Edge with the AddIn activated and the program crashes:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains.

I found a similar CEFSharp issue dealing with the AppDomain-problem (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/351), but I don't really see a solution for my problem.

(Notes: Target Framework is *.NET Framework 4.5*, Output type  *Class Library*. I'm using Visual Studio 2013, programming language is C#).

Comment: As you would have read, the limitation is with the `VC++` implementation. You can try the `RedGate.AppHost`, as outlined in 
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/351#issuecomment-71495187 or you can use one of the `P/Invoke` based `Cef` frameworks for .Net

Comment: That's an exception raised by GCHandle.FromIntPtr().  Usually wrapped by the gcroot<> template in a C++/CLI adapter.   Heap corruption is by far the most common reason, the show is over when the IntPtr gets whacked.  Very hard to debug in a managed app, you can't set a data breakpoint.  CEFSharp is the "solve one problem, add three hard ones" solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pull request (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1556) fully solves my problem. Because it hasn't made its way to CefSharp's master yet, I built it myself and everything works :-)

Let's hope this will be in release branch soon so no one will have to cope with this problem anymore.

Comment: By any chance did u try to test it on Office (Excel-AddIn)? I tried Asher's change in `appdomainsafe` and built it locally. I then copied the DLLs (in `/WinForms.Example/bin/x64/Debug`) over to my project `Debug` folder. But I still get this error, http://imgur.com/8sTBKTQ

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't try it with Office :-/

Comment: Can you tell me how you built it? The process?

Comment: I moved the unamanged dlls into System32 folder so that they are found and it opened up without errors but now I m getting a white screen and the address "google.com" is not loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work for Excel in case, someone wants to know
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1191#issuecomment-215503558